# SQL query to calculate age

Tags: sql, navicat

I am trying to calculate someones age based off of birthday, birthMonth and birthYear. I would like to create an age column and calculate their age based off the 3 other columns stated above.

Thank you

Comment: 1) What database are you using? 2) Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the values look like for birthday, birthMonth and birthYear, and maybe the data types?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I am using Navicat. I ended up going with the below query which worked

ALTER TABLE "12441_load2_all" ADD COLUMN cm_age int8;

update "12441_load2_all" set cm_age = date_part('year',age(("BirthYear"||'-'||"BirthMonth"||'-'||"BirthDay")::date)) where is_date(("BirthYear"||'-'||"BirthMonth"||'-'||"BirthDay"));

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to store the age like this. You will need to update it either every day or every time you query the table, plus every time you insert a new record and every time you correct a birthdate in the other columns. A view or something seems much safer (unless you only want the age at the time the record was created).

Comment: I only needed the age for a project that lasts 3 days and no future records are being added to the table. I didn't need it for a long period of time, but your suggestions are valuable and I appreciate it.